# Azure Search Index - Search For Exact Word

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

We are using Azure Search Index for one of our Search API. We have a field in Azure Search Index say Display Name (which is a string field. The requirement is from the API when we do a search using the Display Name, the search should be an exact search against the fields.

Eg:
If we search for "George Joseph", the Search Index should return only records that exactly match the Display Name as "George Joseph" and it should not return records with names - "George Joseph John" or John George Joseph"

Is there any way I can accomplish this?

Regards,

John

Comment: Just thinking out loud, can you use `filter` instead of using `search`? So your search expression would be `$filter=DisplaName%20eq%20'George Joseph'`.

Comment: Will it support collection of display names? like $filter=DisplayName%20eq%20'George Joseph'&DisplayName%20eq%20'George John'

Comment: Also, we need to have the same feature to be implemented for Person's Educational qualification which is a collection. That can have "Bachelor Desgree", "Master Degree" etc. Is that possible to do that in this case?

Comment: Why not? It's an ODATA filter query so you would construct it something like  `$filter=DisplayName%20eq%20'George Joseph'%20or%20DisplayName%20eq%20'George John'`. Please see this link for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/odata-expression-syntax-for-azure-search. Only catch is that the fields on which you're filtering must have `filterable` attribute set.

Comment: The other catch is that $filter is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter to achieve this, assuming you are interested in case-sensitive matches. For example, `DisplayName eq 'George Joseph'` will match exactly `George Joseph` but will not match `george JOSEPH`. You can find details about the filter syntax [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/searchservice/odata-expression-syntax-for-azure-search).

Answer (score 0):

You can specify "&searchMode=All"

When you set searchMode=all you tell the search engine that all query terms must be matched at least once in the document-

```
agency temps&$count=true&$top=30&$skip=0&searchMode=All&$filter=(CompanyCode eq '13453' and VNumber eq '00023232312016') &scoringProfile=BusinessProfile1&searchFields=VCategory
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-lucene-syntax

The searchMode=all parameter is relevant in this example. Whenever operators are on the query, you should generally set searchMode=all to ensure that all of the criteria is matched.

GET /indexes/hotels/docs?search=category:budget AND "recently renovated"^3&searchMode=all&api-version=2020-06-30&querytype=full